# How to extract text from paragraphs and table using python module from word document having objects excel sheet?

Tags: python, docx

How to extract only text from paragraphs and table using python module from word document having objects like hyperlinks, images, attached excel sheet?

I tried `docx2python` but it only works for simple "docx" files and not for which have links or excel file attached inside of them.

Comment: post example of your document

Comment: I can't post that document as example due to security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
import docx 

doc = docx.Document(FILEPATH)

text = []

for i in range(num_of_pargrphs): 
    line = [run.text for run in doc.paragraphs[i].runs]
    if line != []:
        # If you need a list of paragraphs        
        # text.append(line)

        result = ''.join(line)

# Printing out final results

print(result)
```

Also maybe for reading tables in documents you can use this:
https://github.com/gressa-cpu/Python-Code-to-Share/blob/main/read_word_table.py